# How I can remove bar on Forms in Wince

Tags: forms, windows-ce

Im working on WinCE project and I have a question. 
When project runs on Wince device there is something like a bar on top of forms. in design time I did not put there anything. What is it and how I can remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an empty `MainMenu`.  Remove the `MainMenu` component from your `Form` and it will go away.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt see it at bottom :)